# Why can't I add xib files as subViews to my main xib?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xib, uicontainerview

I have a main `xib` file and would like to add/reuse `subview` xib files to it (like `android studios` `fragments`). I have tested with just a simple `xib` file with a pink background color and it works using this code:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"testXib" bundle:nil];

UIView *sub = [nib instantiateWithOwner:nil options:nil][0];

[containerOutlet addSubview:sub];

[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
    [sub.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:containerOutlet.leadingAnchor],
    [sub.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:containerOutlet.trailingAnchor],
    [sub.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:containerOutlet.topAnchor],
    [sub.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:containerOutlet.bottomAnchor]
]];
```

This presents my colored `xib` in my main `xib`. But as soon as I try to add any of the existing `xib` files instead, the app crash with this error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[< NSObject 0x600000fb9220 > setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key activityIndicatorView.'

The last part: "activityIndicatorView" changes depending of what `xib` file I try to load. Sometimes it's "ViewingNumberBanner" or something else.

The `xib` files are more complex than the working test-`xib` so there is obviously something I must have missed. Problem is I don't know where to start. I should probably mention that all the `xib` files work on their own when used in their regular fashion. Let me know if there is something else you would like to know that can be helpful.

[image]

To illustrate, I have included a picture.

1. The file name. This is the name I use in `nibWithNibName:@"SecondView"`
2. This `xib` has no `class` associated with it. But it seems it has a view with a lot of `xib` files to it if I'm not mistaken (see to the left of the screen).
3. This has `class` ColleagueTableViewController associated with it. This is the `xib` I would like to load. I don't know if this is `index` `[0]` when I use `instantiateWithOwner`, I'm only guessing. How do I know for certain?

Comment: `[NSObject setValue:forUndefinedKey:]` the fact that it's `NSObject`, and not a `UIView` is causing the issue. You didn't set the class of the File owner or I never know which one to "MyCustomView" class.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for helping me out. The file owner is set to class `SecondViewController`. Sorry I don't get the last part of your comment: "I never know which one to "MyCustomView" class". I'm not sure what to do about the `NSObject` thing.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the long view, there are two problems here:

- Nobody should be keeping view controllers in a *.xib* file. That's what *.storyboard* files are for. Even if you don't use segues, storyboards let you instantiate a view controller by an identifier, which you can't do with a *.xib* file. Plus a lot of other good stuff.
- If you are going to want to load view hierarchies from a *.xib* file, the view should be the only thing in that *.xib*. Then you just load it with no owner, pull out the first view, and use it in your interface. If you have multiple such views you'll want to load, use one per *.xib*.